# Dreampie: Switch between the upper and lower screen sections

Tags: python, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

[image: Dreampie interface, with two sections]

The only way I can manage this is by clicking into each section, usually. I have found that you can "reload" an already interpreted line from the the upper half by pressing enter, and then using `ctrl+a, backspace` to delete the line in the staging area below, essentially moving into the bottom half without clicking. But this is very ugly, and I hate reaching for the mouse if I don't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me Ctrl-Tab seems to do that.

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find it anywhere.